# Get newline in terminal after execution of Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, bash

I have an extremely simple `hello.rb` file containing only:

```
print 'Hello world!'
```

I then try to run this file from my Ubuntu 14 terminal using:

```bash
ruby hello.rb
```

However, this ends up looking just about like this:

```
user@machine:~/Documents/Ruby/HelloWorld$ ruby hello.rb
Hello world!user@machine:~/Documents/Ruby/HelloWorld$
```

I guess that's technically correct, but it would be more readable if a newline is inserted after the output Ruby's execution. For regular terminal commands such as `dir` this newline *is* inserted, and the prompt starts on a new line.In other words, I'd like to see this:

```
user@machine:~/Documents/Ruby/HelloWorld$ ruby hello.rb
Hello world!
user@machine:~/Documents/Ruby/HelloWorld$
```

What do I need to change to get this behavior? Do I need to change the way I call Ruby? Or should I change my terminal settings?

Comment: Use `puts` or add a newline in your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `puts` instead of `print`. It adds the newline.